# OpenCV convert color per pixel

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing, colors, pixel

Hello i want to convert the color in image, i'm using per-pixel methods but it seems very slow

```
src.getPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);

        // RGB values
        int R;

        for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++) {
            // Get RGB values as ints


            // Set pixel color
            pixels[i] = color;

        }

        // Set pixels
        src.setPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
```

my question, is there any way i can do it using openCV? change pixel to the color i want ?

Comment: Do you want to fill the whole image with one color or should each pixel have a different color?

Comment: thanks, no each pixel  should have different color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend [this excellent article](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/how_to_scan_images/how_to_scan_images.html) on how to access/modify an opencv image buffer. I recommend 
"the efficient way":

```
 int i,j;
    uchar* p;
    for( i = 0; i < nRows; ++i)
    {
        p = I.ptr<uchar>(i);
        for ( j = 0; j < nCols; ++j)
        {
            p[j] = table[p[j]];
        }
```

Or "the iterator-safe method":

```
MatIterator_<Vec3b> it, end;
for( it = I.begin<Vec3b>(), end = I.end<Vec3b>(); it != end; ++it)
{
   (*it)[0] = table[(*it)[0]];
   (*it)[1] = table[(*it)[1]];
   (*it)[2] = table[(*it)[2]];
}
```

For further optimizations, using `cv::LUT()` (where possible) can give huge speedups, but it is more intensive to design/code.

Comment: Thanks for the link, however, could you add the Information directly to this Answer? Links tend to break with time and then this answer would not be of much use anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You can access Pixels by using:

```
img.at<Type>(y, x);
```

So to change an RGB Value you can use:

```
// read color
Vec3b intensity = img.at<Vec3b>(y, x);

// compute new color using intensity.val[0] etc. to access color values

// write new color
img.at<Vec3b>(y, x) = intensity;
```

---

@Boyko mentioned an [Article](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/how_to_scan_images/how_to_scan_images.html) from OpenCV concerning fast access to the image pixels if you want to iterate over all Pixel. The Method I would prefer from this Article is the iterator Method, as it is only slightly slower than direct pointer access but safer to use.

Example Code:

```
Mat& AssignNewColors(Mat& img)
{
    // accept only char type matrices
    CV_Assert(img.depth() != sizeof(uchar));

    const int channels = img.channels();
    switch(channels)
    {
    // case 1: skipped here
    case 3:
        {
         // Read RGG Pixels
         Mat_<Vec3b> _img = img;

         for( int i = 0; i < img.rows; ++i)
            for( int j = 0; j < img.cols; ++j )
               {
                   _img(i,j)[0] = computeNewColor(_img(i,j)[0]);
                   _img(i,j)[1] = computeNewColor(_img(i,j)[1]);
                   _img(i,j)[2] = computeNewColor(_img(i,j)[2]);
            }
         img = _img;
         break;
        }
    }

    return img;
}
```